# Loading Ajax content in Struts 2 using Struts2 Dojo Plugin

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have a simple problem in loading the contents through Ajax call in Struts 2 (using Struts2 Dojo Plugin). It is loading all the HTML contents from the page properly but if there is any inline JavaScript function inside that page its not loading it all. I don't know if there are some limitations with the struts Ajax.

**This my `parent.jsp`:**

```
<s:head/>
<body>
<div id="casetab2" class="casetab_content">
  <sx:div href="LoadContent" delay="3000">
      Initial Content
  </sx:div>
</div>
</body>
```

**This is my `child.jsp`:**

```
<s:text name="name" label="NAME"/>
<script>alert("hello")</script>
```

**and this is my `struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="LoadContent">
   <result>child.jsp</result>
</action>
```

result:`NAME:<textfield>` is getting displayed but alert message is not coming.

Comment: WTQ? There's some javascript, there's some ajax. Nothing has shown here.

Comment: @RomanC i just added the codes just take a look

Comment: Codes a little bit fixed to you with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue...

Theoretically it should work by simply adding `executeScripts="true"` to your `<sx:div/>`, but if it isn't enough, try playing with the `separateScripts` attribute too.

Answer (score 1):

Alert message is not comming because it's not compiled as a valid javascript. If you turn on firebug you'll see errors count. Use corrected with semicolon version of the code

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">alert("hello");</script>
```

Other errors fixes:

1) Include [head](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/dojo-head.html) tag

2) According to the Andrea's answer use [tag attributes](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/ajax-tags.html)

```
<head>
  <sx:head/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="casetab2" class="casetab_content">
    <sx:div href="LoadContent" delay="3000" separateScripts="false" executeScripts="true">
      Initial Content
    </sx:div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thanks, fixed :). BTW I used it with jquery plugin and it worked fine but searching wiki return 0 result. It seems it's undocumented feature.

Comment: i totally agree with you @RomanC there are no documents related to this which i could have read to get the solution

Comment: @CodeHunter My last comment doesn't relate to your question as far as it jquery plugin issue.